# What's the point in mapping users in SQL Server Data Collection?

Tags: sql-server, monitoring, data-collection

In SQL Server 2012 R2 Enterprise, whenever I check Management\Data Collection, right-click --> Configure Management Data  Warehouse , I see whatever users-accounts-logins except the one I am logged in

[image: Map Logins and Users]

I cannot understand what's the point in "Map Logins and Users" in Management\DataCollectiion of SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the management data warehouse, the current login will be added to all three roles, making it an administrator of the database.

The dialog above lets you add *other* logins to the roles, to make those people readers, writers or administrators of the database.